# Register scroll on page with 100% container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page in which I want to incorporate parralax scrolling. However, with my current code, I am not able to registrate the scroll.

I have a container over the complete page, because I need the containing divs to be 100% in height and width, without using javascript for that.

But now, I cant execute anything on scroll anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTeE8/) i've made of the problem.

The problem forms with the following combination:

Html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="page page-1">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page page-2">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page page-3">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But now, the scroll event isn't captured anymore:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(alert('scrolled'));
});
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use `alert` to debug your code. Use `console`.
2. You should pass a function as event callback, which you don't. You just execute `alert()` while the code is parsed (that's why it alerts immediately, not on scroll), it doesn't return anything, so there's no callback in onscroll event.
3. The element actually being scrolled is `.main`, not `window`, so attach the listener to `.main`.

Putting this all together:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.main').on('scroll', function(e){ console.log(e) });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zTeE8/1/

If you really need alert, then `jQuery('.main').on('scroll', function(e){ alert("scrolled") });`

Comment: I could've known this one. But thanks. And the alert was just for testing purposes in the fiddle right now. Thank you for your complete and helpful answer. I will accept it as answer as soon as I'm able to.

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with the fact you'll scroll the div with `.main` class and not the window.
Try `$('.main').scroll(alert('scrolled'));`

Comment: That's what I thought, but after trying that and failing, I didn't know what else it could be.